# Android testing: how to verify from JUnit testcase if the dialog was opened?

Tags: java, android, junit

I am testing an Android application. Currently I am writing tests for MainActivity. There are some dialogs that get opened when an item from options menu gets selected:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) { 
    case android.R.id.home:    
        new DialogCredits(this).show();         
        return true; 
/.../
}
```

I would like to test if the dialog was successfully opened from JUnit testcase. My current test code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivityFunctionalTest extends 
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private MainActivity activity;
    private @Mock MenuItem item;

    public MainActivityFunctionalTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        activity = getActivity();       
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testOnOptionsItemSelected() {
        when(item.getItemId()).thenReturn(android.R.id.home);
            assertTrue(activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
        // verify that the correct dialog was successfully opened
            // --->code missing here<---
    }
}
```

The code of DialogCredits class:

```
public class DialogCredits extends Dialog{

    public DialogCredits(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(R.string.dialog_credits_title);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_credits);

        final Dialog d = this;

        Button buttonOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_credits_button_ok);
        buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // close dialog
                d.dismiss();            
            }
        });       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/), much less code and better methods like `waitForDialog()`.

Comment: Thanks, I might try it out, but I try to remain white-box at the moment :)

Comment: It seems that I don't get any whitebox solution. It works ok with Robotium, so I'll take it as an answer :)

Comment: @RebaneLumes Robotium isn't exactly black box, you can mix native instrumentation code as well. It just provides easy methods for the usual tasks.

Comment: you are right about this aspect. I also try to avoid Robotium as it is rather slow im comparision with "direct Android methods". :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DialogCredits dialog  = new DialogCredits(this); 

if(!dialog.isShowing())
{  
    dialog.show(); 
}
```

put this code in switch case

Comment: That looks cool, thanks. But how do I get the reference to the dialog?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - should I post the code of DialogCredits?

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at my testcase, I am testing onOptionsItemSelected method, that opens the dialog. I would like to test, if the onOptionsItemSelected method did it's job correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36009/discussion-between-sanket-kachhela-and-rebane-lumes)

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same problem.

What i did was:

```
private YourDialog mDialog;

onCreate :
initDialog();

public void initDialog() {    
mDialog = new YourDialog (this)
    enter code here
}
public boolean isDialogShowing() {
return mDialog.isVisible();
}
```

Well, you must keep reference to the dialog so you can check is visibilty,
If you create new one all the time you will lose the last dialog ref.

Comment: that's a neat option, but if I trigger onOptionsItemSelected from the test class, I cannot know the reference to the dialog, right? Do you know how I could still fetch the reference?

Comment: You can save a listener in the test class which you init with the class, once menu item has been pressed, trigger listener.yourMethod();